# How To Add <td></td> tags to table after some actions

Tags: javascript, html

now i've written some HTML Tags,and some JS & PHP, and the PHP returns some data to the JS then to the HTML, by the return of this data i wanna change in the HTML form.

let's explain it:

The Html contains a table and i want to add some new rows and columns to this table by the returning of new data from php

How Can I Do It ... after i've closed the table tag " ???

Comment: Can you share the code you already have and what you've tried? Also, are you trying to add the new rows in PHP or JavaScript (i.e. before the page loads or after)?

Comment: Wait, do you want to add rows in PHP or JavaScript??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be short, to add a row into a `table`:

```
yourTable.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));  //native

- or -

$("<tr>").appendTo(yourTable);                        //jQuery
```

To add a cell:

```
yourRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));    //native

- or -

$("<td>").appendTo(yourRow);                          //jQuery
```

To append HTML or text into newly-created nodes:

```
yourCell.innerHTML = "Your Text";

- or - 

$(yourCell).html("Your HTML"); / $(yourCell).text("Your text");
```

References: <kbd>[***`document.createElement`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)</kbd> <kbd>[***`Node.appendChild`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)</kbd>

A little demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/rS8H8/

---

You might need to request your data via `XMLHttpRequest` or `$.ajax` and apply the methods mentioned above to achieve the feature you wanted.

Comment: and when i append the child is the closing tag added by default with these children ??

Comment: @Abdel-rahmanEl-Carpenter - You don't really need to care about the closing tags because all JavaScript cares are the nodes, not the HTML.

Comment: @Abdel-rahmanEl-Carpenter - If you are confused, feel free to take a look in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/rS8H8/

Comment: ok, after i've added this node or this child, so how can i add attributes to this child ??

Comment: @Abdel-rahmanEl-Carpenter - To add attributes you can do [`.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) (*native*) or [`.attr({...})`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) (*jQuery*).

Answer (score 0):

Use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to retrieve the data from the server and then use [jQuery `append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add `<td>` tag to the `<table>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsahu/hDs2G/) or
HTML:

```
<table id=mytable border="1">
  <tr><td>rahul</td><td>sahu</td></tr>
</table>
<button>Add New Row</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
   var newRow = "<tr><td>rohit</td><td>sahu</td></tr>";
   $("#mytable").append(newRow);
});
```

Comment: Watch out for [script injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#HTML_Script_Injection) :/